# Push file updates to GitHub

Tags: git, github, commit

So I've done an initial commit on my files from my PC to GitHub with git checkout -b [branch] and git add . and git commit and all that. I've now made a change to that file, how can I update that file on GitHub and add a commit message?

I tried git add on the file but it's already added, and git status says nothing to commit.

Can someone help with this? Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commits-in-git/6866485#6866485

Comment: git push origin [your branch]

Comment: Can you show us the results of the following commands: `git branch -vva` and `git status` and `git remote -vv`

Comment: `git branch -vva` master                      0cfb096 Initial commit
* oreo-8.0.0                  0cfb096 [oblivion/oreo-8.0.0] Initial commit
remotes/oblivion/oreo-8.0.0 0cfb096 Initial commit
`git status` On branch oreo-8.0.0
Your branch is up-to-date with 'oblivion/oreo-8.0.0'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
`git remote -vv` oblivion https://github.com/OblivionMOD/android_packages_apps_Settings.git (fetch)
oblivion https://github.com/OblivionMOD/android_packages_apps_Settings.git (push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I was editing the file in Android Studio, but when I saved the file it was not being picked up by Git or nano for some reason. I edited it in nano and ran git add ., git commit and git push.

Now I just need to know why Android Studio isn't actually saving the files properly...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `push` your branch to the `remote` repository on GitHub with:

`$ git push origin [your-branch-name]`

If the branch does not have a remote repository yet (where remote is the GitHub repo), you will have to add it to your project with:

`$ git remote add origin [the-url-you-obtain-from-your-github-repo]`

Comment: Remote is called oblivion, branch is oreo-8.0.0, running that command gives me "Everything up-to-date" I ran `git push oblivion oreo-8.0.0`

Comment: `git checkout -b` will create a new branch and switch you to that branch. Which branch are you making commits on? and Which branch are you trying to push?

Comment: I'm making commits on oreo-8.0.0 and trying to push to that branch, not using master at all.

Comment: Are you sure you have a remote repo set?